# Issue with storing IP address in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a password reset feature for my site and decided to record the IP address of the requests in case it's reported false.

This is what I have, as a function, for storing all of the info upon initial request:

```
public function insert($memberId, $token)
    {
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$ip = ip2long($ip);
        $query = 'INSERT INTO password_reset (member_id, password_recovery_token, expire_at, ip_address, is_valid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $paramType = 'sssii';
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        
        // expire the token after 12 hours
        $RESET_TOKEN_LIFE = '12 hours';
        $expireAt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time . ' + ' . $RESET_TOKEN_LIFE));

        $paramValue = array(
            $memberId,
            $token,
            $ip,
            $expireAt,
            1
        );
        $memberId = $this->ds->insert($query, $paramType, $paramValue);
    }
```

For some reason, it doesn't store the IP address, it stores the year... Why would it do that? What's causing that?

Comment: Your SQL has `expire_at, ip_address`, your array is `$ip, $expireAt,`

Comment: Not much of a mystery

Answer (score 1):

Try to correct yours params sent. The 4th parameter is **expireAt**, change it for **IP** :

```
$paramValue = array(
            $memberId,
            $token,
            $expireAt,
            $IP,
            1
        );
```

Comment: We usually just point typos out in a comment and then vote to close it as a typo instead of answering them since they rarely are of any help for anyone else. :-)